# When using `cl-labels` or `cl-flet` shouldn't the compiler catch signature msmatches

Tags: byte-compilation, cl

I was expecting a compilation error for the  snippet below... unfortunately compilation goes through without any errors, but it errors during runtime.

Run-time error is expected, so no surprise there.  The surprise is in not getting a compilation error

```lisp
;;; foo.el --- foo -*- lexical-binding: t; coding: utf-8-emacs; -*-

(defun foo ()
  ;; (cl-labels ((msg (s)
  ;;        (message "%s" s)))
  ;;   (msg
  ;;    ;; "Hello World!"
  ;;    ))

  (cl-flet ((msg (s)
          (message "%s" s)))
    (msg 
     ;; "Hello World!"
     )))

(foo)
```

---

Initially I went with

```lisp
;;; foo.el --- foo -*- lexical-binding: t; coding: utf-8-emacs; -*-

(defun foo ()
  (let* ((msg (lambda (s)
        (message "%s" s))))
    (funcall msg
         ;; "Hello World!"
         )))

(foo)
```

and then switched to `cl-labels` and `cl-flet` hoping that it will produce compilation errors.

If I am not getting any compile-time errors, I could as well stay with `lambda` form.  This way I don't have to be mentally bothered with `cl-labels` or `cl-flet` indenting the forms too much to the right.

Comment: Elisp is not a static language.

Comment: I just added `(require 'cl-macs)` ---- it is `cl-macs` and not `cl-lib`---as per your suggestion.  I still don't get byte compiler errors.

Comment: Could you please layout each step in the reasoning from `Elisp is not a static language` to `This is why you don't get compilation errors`.

Comment: `cl-flet` expands to a `let*` form which binds a lambda to a symbol.  Lisp is so dynamic that it is difficult for the compiler to apply static program analysis. You of course know that it will signal an error, because you are intellectual enough, but the compiler is not.